# CWAC camera flash not working

Tags: android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I use `setFlashMode()` in `CameraFragment` to set flash modes. However, flash works only when using autofocus, but now when calling `takePicture()` method. Can anyone shed some light on this? Thank you.

Comment: Other than passing the flash modes along to the `Camera`, I am not really doing anything with them directly.

Comment: Yes i checked that already, but i thought i was missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: File an issue on the repo, providing the exact details of your device(s) (`Build.MANUFACTURER` and `Build.PRODUCT`) and what you're passing to `setFlashMode()` and when. I'll see if I can reproduce your scenario. It is entirely possible that I'll need to add more device-specific flash smarts, on top of everything else.

Comment: I will do that, on another note, flash doesn't work on your demo app either. Just now i compiled and ran it with no alterations at all.

Comment: The demo app requests particular flash modes that may or may not be supported by the device. Beyond that, again, I need to know the specific device(s) to be able to investigate further.

Comment: Nexus 4. Thanks anyway, ill post an issue.

Comment: Demo flash doesn't appear to be working on a Verizon Droid with 4.1. Build.Manufacturer: 'motorola', Product: 'XT912_verizon' my other test device doesn't have a flash.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my phone Galaxy S4 (SPH-L720).
I was able to resolve it by copying the existing Galaxy S4 xml config file and creating a new file specific for my phone: `cwac_camera_profile_samsung_jfltespr.xml`

As mentioned in the comments, you need to include in the filename the Build.MANUFACTURER (`samsung` in this case) and `jfltespr` is the Build.PRODUCT code.

```
<!-- Galaxy S4 (SPH-L720) -->
<deviceProfile>
    <maxPictureHeight>
    2448
    </maxPictureHeight>
    <recordingHint>
    STILL_ONLY
    </recordingHint>
</deviceProfile>
```